# Multiple continuation chaining: boost.future unwrapping. How to do it

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, concurrency, continuations

I am using `boost.future<T>` with continuations, in boost 1.56.

I have an API that returns a future, that I want to use from inside a
continuation. So in theory, I need to `.unwrap` the future before chaining the
second continuation.

So I do the following:

```
auto result = api_returns_future().then([](boost::future<R> && result) {
                    do_something_with_result();

                    //Note I could call .get() here, but I don't
                    return api_returns_future();
              }).unwrap() //Now I unwrap the future here
              .then([](boost::future<R> && result) { ... });
```

Namely, I have:

1. `future<R>::then`
2. In the first continuation, I return from the lambda with an API call that returns a `boost::future<R>` and later I unwrap it.
3. After that I want to attach another continuation, but this continuation is never called.

Question:

1. It would be correct to do this in the first continuation: `return api_returns_future().get()` (note I call `.get()` from inside the continuation directly` and give up on unwrapping?. Has this alternative some drawback for the asynchroncity of my code?

EDIT: I updated the question to better reflect what I want to ask after some more research.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you look in the [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html), there's an example of how to use `then()`:

```
future<int> f1 = async([]() { return 123; });
future<string> f2 = f1.then([](future<int> f) { 
    return f.get().to_string(); // here .get() won't block 
});
```

Note that `then` wraps its lambda's result in a `future` too. Now in your case, your lambda returns a future, so as a first go, you'd have to write:

```
auto result = api_returns_future().then([](future<R> result) {
    // stuff
    return api_returns_future();
}).then([](future<future<R>> result2) {
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // other stuff
});
```

But for this reason, the docs also indicate that there is an [unwrap move constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.unique_future.unwrap_move_constructor):

> ***Unwrap Move Constructor - EXTENSION***
>
> ```
>  future( future< future<R>>& other); // EXTENSION
> ```
>
> **Postconditions**
>   `this->get_state()` returns the value of `other->get_state()` prior to the call. `other->get_state()` returns `boost::future_state::uninitialized`. The associated shared state is now unwrapped and the inner future shared state is associated with `*this`. `other` is not associated with any shared state, `! other.valid()`.

Thus I would expect you to be able to just write the following:

```
auto result = api_returns_future().then([](future<R> result) {
    // stuff
    return api_returns_future();
}).then([](future<R> result2) {
//         ^^^^^^^^^
    // other stuff
});
```

since the library will take care of the unwrapping itself.

Comment: I see what you mean. But my question actually is: I have an API that *already* returns a future. I want to call it from inside the continuation. So if I call `.get()` inside the continuation, will this have adverse effects? I tried to not call `.get` inside the continuation and use `unwrap()` but it is blocked forever for some reason.

Comment: I modified the code to reflect better what I mean, take another look please if you could help.

Comment: I modified my question to more clearly state my current question, which evolved since I wrote it, but it is still basically the same.

Comment: @GermánDiago I believe I understand your question better and updated. Did you ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28103562/boost-future-are-these-two-pieces-of-code-equivalent) twice in a row?

Comment: I will try again but I believe that last time I tried automatic unwrap did not happen.