# boost.future: are these two pieces of code equivalent?

Tags: c++, boost, concurrency

I am concerned about hidden blocking issues that could arise from these two pieces of code. For me, the first one is working, the second one is not. I feel more confident about something like the non-working code wouldn't block, but it is not working correctly.

My question is: are those two pieces of code equivalent or the fact that I have a `.get()` in the first continuation for the working code can make my code blocking at that point?

**Working code.**

```
auto finished = user2.ReceiveChatMessages().then([&]
(boost::future<std::vector<ServerReply>> && receivedMessages) 
    {
        number_received_messages_in_continuation = receivedMessages.get().size();

        //Will this .get make my code block in any case?
        return user2.ReceiveChatMessages().get();
    })
   .then([&](boost::future<std::vector<ServerReply>> && receivedMessages) {
       number_received_messages_in_continuation += receivedMessages.get().size();
});
```

**Non-working code.**

```
auto finished = user2.ReceiveChatMessages().then([&]
(boost::future<std::vector<ServerReply>> && receivedMessages) 
    {
        number_received_messages_in_continuation = receivedMessages.get().size();

        //No .get() here
        return user2.ReceiveChatMessages();
    }).unwrap() //We need to unwrap
   .then([&](boost::future<std::vector<ServerReply>> && receivedMessages) {
       number_received_messages_in_continuation += receivedMessages.get().size();
});
```

Comment: _"[...] that I have a `.get()` [...] can make my code blocking [...] ?"_. Unless you can guarantee that the future _must_ be ready. Yes this is the documented behaviour of `.get()`. (`receivedMessages` is an example of a read future because you only get the continuation called iff it is ready)

Comment: And the latter is also what will happen, of course. Note that those are not mutually exclusive (waiting for it to be ready might block forever if it never becomes ready. This happens e.g. when there is a deadlock (or just a programmer failure :))

Comment: I can't figure out why the non-working code does not work. It does not even with a simple return `boost::async([] { return true });` for the first continuation. It blocks forever. Why? I misunderstood something or it is an implementation bug.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Looks to me it shouldn't even compile then. The second continuation should take a bool: `foo().then([&](boost::future<T>&&) {return true;}).then([&](boost::future<bool>&&) {});` ?

Comment: `api_returns_fut().then([](future<...> && r) { return boost::async([] { return true; }); }).unwrap().then([](future<bool> && r2) { ...; });`. This example never calls the second continuation, why?

Comment: I can only assume the first future isn't ready? Is the `unwrap` necessary there? There could be dragons: [These functions are experimental and subject to change in future versions. There are not too much tests yet, so it is possible that you can find out some trivial bugs :(](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.unique_future.unwrap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the implementation of `boost.future` what prevents non-working code from working:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10964

The code is functionally equivalent but working code is potentially blocking in the `return user2.ReceiveChatMessages().get()`, so if the continuation is executed in the thread that invokes it, it is potentially blocking.

I am not sure about the exact difference with the non-working code, though I know that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have general problems using continuations, let me show what I think is the usual pattern and demonstrate it live:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9534be3ecdb7831)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using boost::async;
using boost::future;

int foo(int i) { return i*2; }

int main() {

    auto consequence = async(boost::bind(foo, 42))
        .then([&](future<int> j) { return j.get()-4; })
        .then([&](future<int> k) { return k.get()/2; })
        .then([&](future<int> l) { return l.get()+2; });

    return consequence.get();
}
```

Which exits with `42`

Comment: Finally it was a bug, in this case, I am pretty sure: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10964